# Facebook SDK 3.5 - Share Dialog on iOS 5

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Does anybody know if it is possible to use new Share Dialog feature on iOS 5 ?
On the facebook official documentation, it is written :

> Note: You can only test the Share dialog on a device that has Facebook for iOS 6.0 or greater. You may also not have access to test this feature while it's in the beta phase.**

How many time will this feature stay in beta phase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Facebook SDK 3.5 for iOS runs on iOS 5.0 and greater. The Native Share Dialog feature works on OS versions supported by the SDK. The docs are actually referring to the version of the Facebook application, and are admittedly easy to mistake for referring to the OS version. We will clarify the docs to avoid further confusion on this point. Thanks for the question!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this answer. Clearer now! BTW, it is not really obvious whether we can use the 3.5 from now on (the doc says it is in beta, but the SDK download page does not refer to any beta stage). Any idea on that?

Comment: @MathieuGodart, yes. This is also a subtle point that we could have doc'd a bit more clearly.

The SDK itself is production. The Facebook app is also production. However, the share dialog API hosted within the Facebook app is currently in beta. At some point we will ship a version of the Facebook app in which that API is no longer in beta. When that happens the already production presentShare* methods in the SDK (3.5, 3.5.1) will be useable in your production applications.

I hope this helps to clarify that point as well.

Answer (score 0):

For ios5, you can use the older web dialog. You can invoke it with something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params =
                [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 @"name/title of post", @"name",
                 @"some description", @"description",
                 @"url to link to", @"link",
                 nil];
// Invoke the dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil parameters:params handler:
                 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                     if (error) {
                         // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.
                         NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
                     } else {

                     }
                 }];
```

You can test if the native dialog is available by capturing the return value presentShareDialogModallyFrom: in FBNativeDialogs.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I need to know if the native share dialog, the new SDK 3.5 feature will be available for iOS 5. 
I work on an app supporting iOS5 and iOS6 so it is very important to know if this feature will be available soon or not as it is still in a beta phase.